# Screen brightness too low

Tags: 16.04, brightness

I'm having the following problem:
My screen brightness is too low, at least for my taste. The problem however, is not that my laptop isn't capable of being brighter, but more that Ubuntu makes it like that. For example, in almost every context or dropdown menu the screen brightness is way brighter than usual. Example images:

[Too dark Taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCfCf.png)

[Taskbar as it should be when I open the search menu at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIvKe.png)

Is there something I can do about this? I don't think it has been like this forever, however I don't really know. The screen brightness is at max.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: [Hardinfo Report](https://jsfiddle.net/rpjuze1s/)

Comment: Can you please provide hardware details of your rig?

Comment: Hardinfo Report: https://jsfiddle.net/rpjuze1s/ (I can't edit because I can't provide more than 2 links).

Comment: Is there a file for max brightness and brightness under `ls /sys/class/backlight/*` and if you change the value of those files does this effects this the brightness of your monitor?

Comment: In fact, there is the file "intel_backlight" containing the stuff you asked for. However, I cannot change the values (even as root, it gives me errors) and the max value is a strange 852. It changes when I adjust brightness.

Comment: @lappen68, which driver are you using `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA" -A2`?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [17aa:5037]
 Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: @lappen68, Could you please add the output of `ls -a /sys/class/backlight` in your post.